# Не отрисовываются элементы при выборе BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing

Имеется некоторая форма, на которой по нажатию кнопки отрисовывается кастомный элемент. Если для панели на которой отрисовываются элементы использовать GridLayout, то все отрисовывается нормально, но при использовании BoxLayout при нажатии кнопки ничего не отрисовывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Код:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel textLabel;
    private JExtendedLabel extTextLabel;
    private JPanel outputPanel;
    private JButton button;

    public MainFrame(){
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        final Row row = new Row();
        row.setName("This is test2. Very small test2. Testing new line2");
        Span[] spansArr = {new Span(5,3,30.778f), new Span(11, 5, 77.778f), new Span(17, 4, 12.778f), new Span(21, 4, 99.778f)};
        row.setSpans(spansArr);


        button = new JButton("Analyze");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                extTextLabel.addRowAndCompile(row);

            }
        });

       ...

        outputPanel = new JPanel();

** Для данного варианта отрисвывает

        outputPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Output"));
outputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

** Для данного варианта нет

outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        textLabel = new JLabel(row.getName());
        outputPanel.add(textLabel);

        extTextLabel = new JExtendedLabel(textLabel.getFont());
        outputPanel.add(extTextLabel);

        add(outputPanel);

        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

JExtendedLabel:

```
public class JExtendedLabel extends JLabel {

private Font textFont;
private Font percentageFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 8);
private String percentageFormat = "%.1f";

private String text;

private boolean analyzeFlag = false;
private Span[] spans = null;



private static final int RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 50;
private static final Color POS_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
private static final Color GRID_COLOR = Color.black;



public JExtendedLabel(Font f){
    textFont = f;
    text = "";
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("paintComponent");
    if (!analyzeFlag){
        super.paintComponent(g);
    } else {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("startingAnalyzePaintComponent");
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(textFont);
        FontRenderContext textFRC = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        g2.setFont(percentageFont);
        FontRenderContext percentageFRC = g2.getFontRenderContext();

        System.out.println("text: " + text + "fullwidth: " + (float) textFont.getStringBounds(text, textFRC).getWidth());

        int position = 0;
        final float coordX = 0.0f;
        final float coordY = 1.0f;
        final float percentageCoordY = RECTANGLE_HEIGHT + 10;

        Span span = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
            span = spans[i];
            if (span.getStart() == position) {
                float prevStrWidth = (float) textFont.getStringBounds(text.substring( 0, span.getStart()), textFRC).getWidth();
                float strWidth = (float) textFont.getStringBounds(text.substring(span.getStart(), span.getStart() + span.getLength()), textFRC).getWidth();
                if (span.getPercent() < 0.5f) {

...

                } else if (span.getPercent() > 99.5f ) {

...

                } else {
                    g2.setPaint(POS_COLOR);
                    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(coordX + prevStrWidth, coordY + (RECTANGLE_HEIGHT - RECTANGLE_HEIGHT * span.getPercent() / 100), strWidth, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT * span.getPercent() / 100));
                    g2.setColor(GRID_COLOR);
                    g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(coordX + prevStrWidth, coordY, strWidth, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT));
                    g2.setFont(percentageFont);
                    String percentageString = String.format(percentageFormat, span.getPercent());
                    float percentageStringWidth = (float) percentageFont.getStringBounds(percentageString, percentageFRC).getWidth();

                    g2.drawString(percentageString, coordX + prevStrWidth + strWidth/2 - percentageStringWidth/2, percentageCoordY);
                }
                position = span.getStart() + span.getLength();
            } else {
                float prevStrWidth = (float) textFont.getStringBounds(text.substring( 0, span.getStart()), textFRC).getWidth();
                float strWidth = (float) textFont.getStringBounds(text.substring(span.getStart(),  span.getStart() + span.getLength()), textFRC).getWidth();
                if (span.getPercent() < 0.5f) {

...

                } else if (span.getPercent() > 99.5f ) {

...

                } else {
                    g2.setPaint(POS_COLOR);
                    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(coordX + prevStrWidth, coordY + (RECTANGLE_HEIGHT - RECTANGLE_HEIGHT * span.getPercent() / 100), strWidth, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT * span.getPercent() / 100));
                    g2.setColor(GRID_COLOR);
                    g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(coordX + prevStrWidth, coordY, strWidth, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT));
                    g2.setFont(percentageFont);
                    String percentageString = String.format(percentageFormat, span.getPercent());
                    float percentageStringWidth = (float) percentageFont.getStringBounds(percentageString, percentageFRC).getWidth();

                    g2.drawString(percentageString, coordX + prevStrWidth + strWidth/2 - percentageStringWidth/2, percentageCoordY);
                }
                position = span.getStart() + span.getLength();
            }
        }

    }

}

public void addRowAndCompile(Row row){
    if (row != null && row.getSpans() != null && row.getName() != null){
        this.analyzeFlag = true;
        this.spans = row.getSpans();
        this.setText(row.getName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Row is null or Spans are null or String is null");
    }
}

@Override
public void setText(String text) {
    System.out.println("starting setText");
    this.text = text;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: У меня не получилось вопроизвести вашу проблему. Чаще всего, если что-то не появляется после добавления в контейнер, то надо пробовать revalidate() и repaint().

Comment: @Arsenicum, т.е. при использовании и того и другого  'LayoutManager`а (по отдельности само собой) все нормально отрисовывется после нажатия кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в ваш `paintComponent` заливку фона и вы сами все увидите. `GridLayout` делит весь контейнер (`outputPanel`) на равные части, и растягивает содержащийся в ячейке компонент по размеру ячейки. `BoxLayout` спрашивает размеры у самого компонента, вызывая `getMinimumSize`, `getPreferredSize` и `getMaximumSize`. У пустого `JLabel` эти методы возвращают (0, 0).

Вам нужно переопределить эти методы (либо вызвать `super.set___Size`), и вызвать `revalidate()`, чтобы уведомить контейнеры об изменении размера вашего компонента.